# How to import specific css files to components in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a website which running on angular.But I need to declare my css files in some of components not all of them.When I import them in components some of my files does not load.Here is my file structure

---home

--components

--home

-home-footer

-home-navbar

-home-invest

--network

Im pretty sure about importing @import '../../../assets/css/responsive.css';
Im using home-footer navbar in home.component.html(in ---home)

Comment: So you only want those external styles to show in some components? If you have control of the styles in assets, can't you just adjust your selectors?

Comment: I got assets file and imported but some of files conflict with each other i guess.I imported same file in 3 component and 3 of them in same page.How can ı prevent that

Answer (score 0):

Just use styleUrls in component. you can use multiple stylesheet in style URL's

```
@Component({ 
selector: 'app-home', 
templateUrl: './home.component.html', 
styleUrls: [ './home.component.css',
'../../../assets/css/responsive.css'
], 
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None })
```

Comment: here is my @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
}) and home component css @import '../../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
etc

Comment: @EralpOnay ViewEncapsulation.None is going to cause imported styles to apply to parents. Is it there for a reason?

Comment: yeah my child components css files was not load because of the encapsulation but now ı got 8 files and one of them wont load.

Comment: @EralpOnay But why have you turned encapsulation off? If you have no reason for it, then remove it. This will only apply the imported styles to the component, not its parent

Comment: Im using some css files in parent too.